# Sass: Proper way to nest element within modifier with the same block name?

Tags: css, sass

The HTML (which I am unable to alter) looks like:

```
<div class="cta">
  <div class="cta--red">
    <div class="cta__inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to target the content within this - specific to the red, inner cta.

I can do this with:

```
.cta {
  &--red{
    .cta {
      &__inner {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But is there a cleaner way of writing this? (note: my company insists on having each element and modifier on a line break)

I seem to recall something like:

```
.cta {
  &--red & {
    &__inner {
    }
  }
}
```

but can't quite remember what it's called.

The desired CSS output is: `.cta--red .cta-inner {}`

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the parent selector:

```
.cta {
  $this: &;

  &--red {
    // -> .cta--red

    & #{$this}__inner {
      // -> .cta--red .cta__inner
    }
  }
}
```

A more clean option, in my opinion:

```
.cta {
  // -> .cta

  .cta--red {
    // -> .cta .cta--red

    .cta__inner {
      // -> .cta .cta--red .cta__inner
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
.cta {
  &--red {

  }
  &__inner {

  }
}
```

Comment: But wouldnt that target each individually? I need inner nested within red. Eg, the css output I need would be: `.cta--red .cta-inner {`